# r - Add variable in column according to specific date in year

Tags: r, date

I have a table including a time series of daily values and a variable "x":

```
# x<-100
#    date      user_id index  re
# 1 2013-11-07 ff268cef0c29     1
# 2 2013-11-02 12bb7af7a842     1
# 3 2013-11-30 e45abb10ae0b     1
# 4 2013-11-06 e45abb10ae0b     2
# 5 2013-11-25 f266f8c9580e     1
```

Date is formatted as Date using the "as.Date" function.
now I want to add "x" to the value in column "re" on a specific day, eg. on the 01.04. of every year in the time series. 
how to do that best? 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps something like `DF$re[format(DF$Date, "%m-%d") == "01-04"] <- ..` could be helpful?

Comment: I think the poster meant column `re` since that is the name of the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2013-04-01", 
                                "2013-04-02", 
                                "2014-04-01")), 
                 re=1:3)
x <- -100
i <- which(format(df$date, "%d.%m.") == "01.04.") 
df$re[i] <- df$re[i] + x
#         date  re
# 1 2013-04-01 -99
# 2 2013-04-02   2
# 3 2014-04-01 -97
```